# Spring mvc select button

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I want to create simple html select tags with some populated values(for now what I type, later from database). Here is my controller :

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping("/test")

    public String home(){
        return "index";
    }

    @ModelAttribute("items")
    public ArrayList<String> getList(){
        ArrayList<String> itemList = new ArrayList<String>();
        itemList.add("one");
        itemList.add("two");
        itemList.add("three");
        return itemList;
    }

}
```

In my index part here is HTML code that is relevant :

```
<div class="form-row">
   <label for="items">Items:</label>
   <span class="input"><form:select path="items" items="${items}" itemLabel="name" /></span>
</div>
```

This produces(this is rendered into html) :

```
<div class="form-row">

   <label for="items">Items:</label>

   <span class="input"><form:select path="items" items="[one, two, three]" itemLabel="name" /></span>

</div>
```

And I had something else in mind like this(what I expected to produce) :

```
<div class="form-row">

       <label for="items">Items:</label>

       <span class="input"><select name="name">
       <option>one</option>
       <option>two</option>
       <option>three</option>
       </select></span>

    </div>
```

I could alter my getList() method by adding `<option>` before and `</option>` before each item in arrayList, I'm sure there is a pretier way to do this that is why I'm asking here, please bare in mind that I'm only starting to learn spring MVC. thank you

**QUESTION UPDATE :**

When I edit this according to skaffman suggestion, added this :

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form" %>
```

after

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt" %>
```

and it caused this exception :

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /WEB-INF/views/index.jsp at line 39

36:     Date of birth: <input type="text" size="10" />
37:     <div class="form-row">
38:    <label for="items">Items:</label>
39:    <span class="input"><form:select path="items" items="${items}" itemLabel="name" /></span>
40: </div>
41:   </fieldset>
42:  


Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:498)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:411)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:322)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:249)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:250)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1063)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:801)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:549)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.NormalRewrittenUrl.doRewrite(NormalRewrittenUrl.java:195)
    org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.handleRewrite(RuleChain.java:159)
    org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.doRules(RuleChain.java:141)
    org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriter.processRequest(UrlRewriter.java:90)
    org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:417)
    org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
root cause

org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'name' of bean class [java.lang.String]: Bean property 'name' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?
    org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:702)
    org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:694)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.OptionWriter.doRenderFromCollection(OptionWriter.java:210)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.OptionWriter.renderFromCollection(OptionWriter.java:180)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.OptionWriter.writeOptions(OptionWriter.java:133)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.SelectTag.writeTagContent(SelectTag.java:216)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractFormTag.doStartTagInternal(AbstractFormTag.java:102)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag.doStartTag(RequestContextAwareTag.java:79)
    org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.index_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005fselect_005f0(index_jsp.java:206)
    org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:109)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:369)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:322)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:249)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:250)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1063)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:801)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:549)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.NormalRewrittenUrl.doRewrite(NormalRewrittenUrl.java:195)
    org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.handleRewrite(RuleChain.java:159)
    org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.doRules(RuleChain.java:141)
    org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriter.processRequest(UrlRewriter.java:90)
    org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:417)
    org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is your error:

> Invalid property 'name' of bean class [java.lang.String]: Bean property 'name' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?

You're getting this because you've told the tag to use the `name` property of each item in the list, when generating the `<option>` labels. But your list consists of Strings, which have no `name` property.

Just remove that from the tag, and you'll be fine, i.e.:

```
<form:select path="items" items="${items}" />
```